# How to exclude empty params?

Tags: c#, flurl

i'm building an url using flurl.
This is an example of what i am doing:

```
var res = baseUrl.AppendPathSegment(a).SetQueryParam(b);
```

I would like to make flurl skip adding "a" or "b" when they are string.empty. Is that possible?

At the moment i see that flurl is adding "a" and "b" to the url even if they are empty.

Thank you

Comment: Adding an empty string won't affect the url at all, so why worry?

Comment: The url will be built like this: "https://example.com//?b="
There is a double backslash and an empty value. Could this be an issue?

Comment: I just tested using the double slash and query string b= on a website I've built and it caused no issues. If you are that concerned about it, use an `if` or `case` statement to exclude the call to `AppendPathSegment` or `SetQueryParam` if the parameter is empty string or null

Comment: I would have expected:

IF a is empty and b is not empty => example.com/?b=somevalue
IF a is not empty and b is empty => example.com/somevalue/

Is it possible to achieve this with flurl?

EDIT: unfortunately having empty parameter cause a 404 on the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's test a few scenarios:

```
"http://example.com/".AppendPathSegment("").AppendPathSegment("")
```

Result: `http://example.com/`, which (if I understand you correctly) is exactly what you want. But, `AppendPathSegment` will throw an exception if you pass null, so I would suggest this in your case:

```
baseUrl.AppandPathSegment(a ?? "")
```

Next up:

```
"http://example.com/".AppendPathSegment("").SetQueryParam("x", null)
```

Also leaves you with `http://example.com/`. But an empty string value (instead of `null`) will append `?x=`, so you may need to replace any empty string with `null` in this case.

However, it looks like you're using the less-common overload of `AppendQueryParam` that takes a single argument.

```
"http://example.com/".SetQueryParam("")
"http://example.com/".SetQueryParam(null)
```

In both cases the result is `http://example.com/?`. The server *shouldn't* behave differently in this case than it would without the `?`, but if you're finding that's not true in your case, then Flurl doesn't have a built-in way to deal with it. You'll need to either avoid it with an `if` statement or use `TrimEnd('?')` on the string result.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the path segment or query param because the parameter `a` or `b` is empty or null use an `if` statement:

```
var res = baseUrl;

if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(a))
{
    res = res.AppendPathSegment(a);
}
if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(b))
{
   res = res.SetQueryParam(b);
}
```